# Deleting commas in R Markdown html output

Tags: html, r-markdown

I am using R Markdown to create an html file for regression results tables, which are produced by `stargazer` and `lfe` in a code chunk.

```
library(lfe); library(stargazer)
data <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = rnorm(10), z = rnorm(10))
result <- stargazer(felm(y ~ x + z, data = data), type = 'html')
```

I create a html file win an inline code `r result` after the chunk above. However, a bunch of commas appear at the top of the table.

[image]

When I check the html code, I see almost every </tr> is followed by a comma. 
How can I delete these commas?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not what you are looking for exactly but I am a huge fan of `modelsummary`. I knit to HTML to see how it looks and then usually knit to pdf. The `modelsummary` equivalent would look something like this

```
library(lfe)
library(modelsummary)
data = data.frame(x = 1:10, y = rnorm(10), z = rnorm(10))

results = felm(y ~ x + z, data = data)


modelsummary(results)
```

There are a lot of ways to customize it through `kableExtra` and other packages. The [documentation](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary/articles/modelsummary.html) is really good. Here is kind of a silly example

```
library(kableExtra)

modelsummary(results,
             coef_map = c("x" = "Cool Treatment",
                          "z" = "Confounder",
                          "(Intercept)" = "(Intercept)")) %>% 
  row_spec(1, background = "#F5ABEA")
```